# Using purr::map to rename columns based on another list in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have multiple files and I want to rename the second column of each file with a name coming from the
`samples=c("sample1","sample2")` dataset. As I am learning purr::map functions, I am struggling to do the renaming with the inside map.

Here is an example:
Any help is extremely appreciated

```
library(purrr)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

files <- paste0("file", 1:3, ".txt") 

## Create example files in a temp dir
temp <- tempdir()

walk(files, ~ write.csv(iris[1:2], file.path(temp, .x), row.names = FALSE))

files |> 
  map(~ fread(file.path(temp, .x)) %>% rename(test = 1, samples=2))
```

Of course, this does not work, but this is here I am so far.

Comment: i believe you must paste the file.path into a single string, as in: `file.path(glue::glue("{temp}/{.x})`

Comment: mmm, maybe you are right. I can reproduce it and read the files the way it is but I am missing adding a sample1 to the first list and a sample2 to the second list. Sorry if I am out of topic

Comment: try `rename_with`, similar to : `iris %>%
rename_with(.cols = c(1:2), ~c("m", "j"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

We use `map2()` and loop over both `files` and `samples` and for each file we first read in the data `fread(file,path(temp, .x))` and then pipe that into `rename(., test = 1, !! sym(.y) := 2))`.

`samples` contains strings. We need to make the strings into object names  with `sym` (or alternatively `as.name()`) and evaluate them with `!!`. If we use this kind of syntax on the lefthand side we also need the walrus operator `:=` instead of `=`.

```r
samples=c("sample1","sample2", "sample3")

files |> 
  map2(samples, ~ fread(file.path(temp, .x)) %>% rename(., test = 1, !! sym(.y) := 2))
```

If you want to rename a different column in every `data.frame` its better to construct a list of lists as below and splice each sublist into `rename()` with `!!!`. (The example below just uses the second column but we could change that to any column number we want).

```r
samples = list(
  list("sample1" = 2),
  list("sample2" = 2),
  list("sample3" = 2)
)

files |> 
  map2(samples, ~ fread(file.path(temp, .x)) %>% rename(., test = 1, !!! .y))
```

---

Since you are using `data.table` to read-in the data we don't need `dyplr::rename()` to rename the colums. Especially the case where you want to rename each second column is easier with `data.table::setnames()`:

```r
samples = c("sample1", "sample2","sample3")

files |> 
  map2(samples, ~ fread(file.path(temp, .x)) %>% setnames(., 1, .y))
```

Comment: this is beautiful !

Comment: @LDT see my data.table update!